# Access Pivotal SSO tile in local development

Tags: spring-security, single-sign-on, cloud-foundry

Our OPS team have configured a SSO tile that connects to ADFS.  I am building a sample application that utilize an SSO service instance.  I can deploy my application to PCF and remote debug my SSO configuration.  These things work.

What I need is a way to access the SSO service instance while I am developing on my PC.  Otherwise only way to verify my code really works is to deploy my application to PCF and either add log statements or configure remote debugging.  Both of these are pretty time consuming.

I looked into configuring ssh access to pivotal services.  That works for database service instances, but not for SSO service instance.  Has anyone figured it out?

Comment: Not necessary to have your App deployed in PCF to test the SSO Services. You can set the `redirect URL` to your `localhost` in the SSO Service and can still run your App locally ...

Comment: How the SSO service will know it is bound to the local application?  The steps i am following are - create a SpringBoot application with SSO support, configure SSO service in PCF with a redirect url to local, run SpringBoot application locally.  How the application and SSO service will know they are bound?

Comment: In addition to making the redirect localhost, so it redirects properly when run locally, you need to create a service key and pass the client credentials into your app when it's run locally. On PCF, the binding will provide this info. Locally that doesn't happen, so you need to make a service key or reuse an existing service binding and manually pass in those values to the app.

Comment: @daniel - could you elaborate on that.  I have created the service key for my SSO service instance.  How do I manually pass these value in the application?  Is there any example you can point me to?

Comment: That depends. You would just copy and paste them into your applications local configuration files, or hard code if your app/framework doesn't have config files. For example, Spring Boot has application.properties or application.yml, you could add the configuration here. The other option with Spring Boot would be to set/export `VCAP_SERVICES` on your local machine. If you set it to a JSON blob with the same format that CF uses, then you can use Spring Cloud Connectors to extract the config info, just like on CF.

Comment: I did "cf env myapp".  Then converted and added vacp services like below in my application.yml file. It does not work.  This is what you meant, correct? 
 `VCAP_SERVICES: 
  p-identity:
    credentials:
      auth_domain: my domain,
      client_id: my id
      client_secret: my secret
    instance_name: my SSO instance`

Answer (score 1):

After repeated trials and error, I found the solution.  Posting it here in case someone else has similar issue

- In PCF, for your SSO add a new application.  Auth redirect url for this application should point to your localhost.  In my case it is http://localhost:8080
- run cf env .  Copy the p-identity section only and save to vcap_services.json.  Then update the clientId and clientSecret with the values from the new application created in previous step.
- Use the following command to start your application

  VCAP_APPLICATION=true VCAP_SERVICES=$(cat vcap_services.json) SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=... ./gradlew bootRun